# Heap's Algorithm - Non Recursive Method in Python to generate permutations

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I am a newbie to programming. I am working on Heap's Algorithm, specifically non-recursive method. There is not so much explanation available on internet, to how the algorithm works. I found this piece of work from [Bernardo Sulzbach](https://www.bernardosulzbach.com/heaps-algorithm/) but he doesn't explain how his algorithm works. I am stuck on it from days, tried everything couldn't figure it out. I have added comments after each line to make myself understand -- what's happening here? but I still couldn't make it work. Am I doing something wrong? Please help.

```
# Heap's Algorithm (Non Recursive)

# function to swap values in python
def swap(elements, i, j):
    elements[i], elements[j] = elements[j], elements[i]

# function to generate permutation
def generate_permutations(elements, n): 
    # Passing two parameters of elements and n to function "generate_permutations".
    c = [0] * n 
    # c is a new list and its value set to an array literal with value 0, n times.
    # Example - [a] * 3 ==> ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
    yield elements 
    # "yield" statement is used to define generators, while "return" statement causes a function to exit.
    # "yield" replacing the return of a function to provide a result to its caller without destroying
    # local variables. Unlike a function, where on each call it starts with new sets of variables, a generator
    # will resume the execution where it left off.
    i = 0
    # i is a new variable and its value is set to 0. It can also be used to count the number of loop runs.
    while i < n:
    # while loop ==> while i is less than n, do following:
        if c[i] < i:
        # if statement ==> while i is less than n and if any element from 'c' list is less than i, 
        # then do following:
            if i % 2 == 0:
            # if statement ==> while i is less than n, and if any element in 'c' list is less than i, and
            # i is an even number, then do following:
                swap(elements, 0, i)
                # calling swap function and passing following arguments: elements, '0' and 'i'
            else:
            # else, if all three conditions above are not true then do following:
                swap(elements, c[i], i)
                # calling swap funtions and passing following arguments: elements, an item from 'c' list and 'i'
            yield elements
            # ??? yield elements
            c[i] += 1
            # after that, increment c[i] by 1.
            i = 0
            # set the value of i to 0
        else:
            # else, if c[i] < i is not true the do the following.
            c[i] = 0
            # set the value of c[i] to 0
            i += 1
            # and increment i by 1

def permutations(elements):
    return generate_permutations(elements, len(elements))

# Driver Code
# c = ?
# n = ?
# i = ?
print(permutations(['abc']))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept (tick the check-mark next to an answer) and possibly up-vote it when it answers your question, so that your question stops from showing up as unanswered in the searches.

Comment: Currently you're asking for someone here to explain the complete algorithm as you have found it – which may be is still too broad. If you can focus your question to some particular part of this iterative implementation of the [Heap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) then that would be a better question. For example, if your problem is that you don't understand how the `c` array is used in this implementation then that would be a more specific question.

Comment: Also sometimes it can also help to increase ones understanding by "executing" an implementation / algorithm by hand on a piece of paper ;)

Comment: @IvoMori Thank you so much for your kind feedback. I am new to Stack Overflow and also programming. I will try my best to keep my questions specific and short next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cleaning up your code (too many comments):

```
# Heap's Algorithm (Non Recursive)
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

def swap(seq, i, j):
  seq[i], seq[j] = seq[j], seq[i]

def generate_permutations(seq, seqLen, resLen): 
  c = [0] * seqLen
  yield seq[:resLen]
  
  i = 0
  while i < seqLen:
    if c[i] < i:
      if i % 2 == 0:
        swap(seq, 0, i)
      else:
        swap(seq, c[i], i)
      yield seq[:resLen]
      c[i] += 1
      i = 0
    else:
      c[i] = 0
      i += 1

def permutations(seq, resLen=None):
  if not resLen: resLen = len(seq)
  return generate_permutations(seq, len(seq), resLen)

for p in permutations([1,2,3]): print(p)
for p in permutations([1,2,3],2): print(p)
```

Comment: it works only for numbers: – How so? If you pass in `['a', 'b', 'c']` instead of `[1, 2, 3]` then you'll get the expected permutations.

Comment: @IvoMori, it works with strings too. You can try it. I tried and it worked for me in the first go.

Comment: @IvoMori Right, I had mixed `c` with something else. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @volothud just a quick question? is there a way to set the length of generated permutation. Let's say I input a list [1, 2, 3] and it outputs [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1] .... so on.

Comment: @Avy I'll try to look into it, but I think that what you are asking for now is combinations, not permutations. For their differences see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination. You might want to look into itertools: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html (permutations(), combinations() functions).

Comment: @volothud Thank you so much for your quick response. I understand the difference between combinations and permutations, I am specifically looking for permutations, hence Heap's Algorithm. Maybe my question was not clear enough. And yes, you are correct I can user Itertools. Itertools are way much simpler, they are basically two lines of code. But Itertools are very resource hungry, but Heap's Algorithm is very efficient and fast as compared to any other solution, especially when there are too many element in a list.

Comment: @volothud Heap's Algorithm is a very complex algorithm, it is believed that 99.9% developers don't understand "Why" it works. I mean they understand how it works? But it is for sure a very difficult algorithm.

Comment: @Avy But, if you have a sequence of 3 elements, and want all 2-combinations, well that's not a permutation anymore right? It's a (3 2) combination. Heap's algorithm won't help you, if it is an algorithm to generate permutations. You will have to find another algorithm; one that generates combinations.

Comment: @volothud Here is my counter argument – The general definition of combinations is when the order of elements does not matter, for example [1, 2] & [2, 1] are same, a combination of two elements '1' and '2' in each case. But in permutations order does matter, so, [1, 2] & [2, 1] are not same they are two separate things. Even in Itertools you can set a length to the permutations >>> print list(permutations('abc', 2)) will give you following output [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]. I am trying to achieve the same with Heap's algorithm not Itertools.

Comment: @Avy Hmm ok, I'll look into it again. (But don't get your hopes up:P)

Comment: @Avy Updated the code. Is this what you want? (It seems that this is what itertools is doing, judging by the result.)

Comment: Just to clarify: limiting the result length like this, will not give real combinations; just truncated permutations.

Comment: @volothud Thank you so much. I will look into that. I truly appreciate the effort.